# Altura miníma do tamanho da tela, com materialize?

Tags: html5, layout-responsivo, resolução-de-tela, materialize

Estou tentando fazer uma tela de `login` simples no `MaterializeCSS`, nela tenho uma logomarca, um painel com o formulário de login e o rodapé, como é pouco conteúdo, em alguma telas a página acaba e embaixo fica um conteúdo em branco. Como na imagem:

[image: tela de login]

Reparem após o rodapé, a página está branca. Quero saber como estendo o meu corpo (o de cor salmão clara) para a página ficar sempre na altura do monitos ou maior, e nunca ter esse espaço branco..

Segue o código da página:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Leonardo Vilarinho
 * Date: 13/04/2016
 * Time: 13:07
 */
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Template Inicial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="materialize-red lighten-2">
        <div class="row">
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m12 ">
                <img src="img/img-l.jpg" width="180"  class="responsive-img materialboxed center-block" alt="Logomarca">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l6 offset-l3">
                <form>
                    <div class="card white darken-1">
                        <div class="card-content black-text">
                            <span class="card-title">Entrar</span>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input id="username" type="text" class="validate">
                                    <label for="username">Usuário</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                                    <label for="password">Senha</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action right-align">
                            <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn amber darken-2"><i class="material-icons "></i>Registrar</button>
                            <button class="waves-effect waves-red btn"><i class="material-icons left"></i>Entrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="page-footer">
            <div class="footer-copyright">
                <div class="container">
                    &copy; 2016 Direitos reversados IFTM
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

P.S: Sempre trabalhei com o BootStrap, migrei hoje para o MaterializeCss por conta do design mais moderno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa fazer um "sticky footer". Existem várias maneras de fazer isso.

Por exemplo, você pode colocar uma altura ao footer e diminuir essa altura da seção anterior.

```
<body>
  <div class="page-wrap">      
    .
    .
    .          
  </div>
  <footer class="page-footer">
      <div class="footer-copyright">
          <div class="container">
              &copy; 2016 Direitos reversados IFTM
          </div>
      </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Código CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -20px; /* Altura do footer */
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.page-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 20px; 
}
.page-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Divida sua pagina html com as tags `main` e `footer`.
Mais ou menos assim:

```
<body>
   <main> ...seu conteudo </main>
   <footer> ...seu rodape </footer>
</body>
```

então adicione esse estilo no seu css:

```
body { display: flex; min-height: 100vh; flex-direction: column; }

main { flex: 1 0 auto; }
```

Assim seu rodape(`footer`) vai ficar sempre na parte inferior da tela e quando o conteudo chegar nele ele desce sozinho.
 Fonte: http://materializecss.com/footer.html (no final da pagina).